# How to have variable values go to different forms without use of objects from toolbox (eg: buttons,textbox,etc)

Tags: c#

So I'm creating a car drag racing game for my project.My game has the concept of money so I need that value to transfer to other forms such as purchasing upgrades, purchasing different cars, main menu, and when winning a race, I would update the money.

My issue is i cant figure out to transfer the int value across the different forms.I want to try to create a global variable but I'm not sure how too. I'm also open to different methods as I heard global variables is frowned upon.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use internal or public for the var.

Or make the new form to get the var via constructors.

```
public class Employee
{
    public int salary;

    public Employee(int annualSalary)
    {
        salary = annualSalary;
    }

    public Employee(int weeklySalary, int numberOfWeeks)
    {
        salary = weeklySalary * numberOfWeeks;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you the suggestion but im new to programming so what do you mean go internal or public for the variable?